# PHP: Passing id from a button tag to a modal which will be used to run php script

Tags: php, html

I've a table with multiple rows containing a button tag which opens a modal.

I want to pass the row id as I want to run a PHP script to select some values from a MySQL table.

Here is my button tag code:

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm\" data 
toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#info<?php echo $row['0'];?>\">";
                echo "Info"; echo"</button>";
                echo "</td>";
```

And below is my modal tag code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="info<?php echo $row['0'];?>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Replica Table </h4>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><b>Device name:</b>XYZ<br><br>
            <b>Manufecturer name:</b>XYZ<br><br>
            <b>Total no:</b>12<br><br>
            <b>sold no:</b>12<br>
            <br><br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $row['0'] ?>;</th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['0'] ?></th>
                    <th>IP Address</th>
                    <th>GPS</th>
                    <th>SOLD/AVAILABLE</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>key</th>
                </tr>
```

I get the error below:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks to me as if you have forgotten a few semicolons `;` or they are in the wrong place. `<?php echo $variable; ?>` can be written as `<?=$variable;?>` in case of interest.

Comment: thanks @qräbnö and which line of code you're referring to?

Comment: Modal: 2, 19 and 20.

Comment: It's not working man!

Comment: The next guess: `<?=$row['0'];?>` is not working? Strangeness. Maybe we have another prob.

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="info<?=$row['0'];?>" role="dialog"> , I've done this and have also changed line 19 and 20 but nothing is being shown on the table

Comment: The next next guess: Maybe `$row['0']` is empty? Maybe you need `$row[0]`? Can you make a better example? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and add some MySQL code in your initial question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#info".$row['0']."\">";
echo "Info";
echo"</button>";
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! the error now is removed but still I cant access the variable passed in the modal body

Answer (score 1):

No need to write the PHP tag  inside echo. Try with below code if it works for you.

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#info".$row['0']."\">";
            echo "Info"; 
            echo"</button>";
            echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! the error now is removed but still I cant access the variable passed in the modal body.